# Python elif statement syntax error

Tags: python-3.x

I am new in python programming. I am facing problem on `elif`statement. I can't find out the syntax error. My code given below.

```
for num in range(1,31):  

       if (num%5 == 0) or (num%3 == 0):  

          if (num%3 == 0):
             print ("beep")
             elif (num%5 == 0):
                print ("boop")
             else:
                print ("beepboop")

       else:          

      print (num)
```

Comment: Is this how you intended the code?

Comment: Yes.. This is my full code ..

Comment: I suspect this won't do what you want even when you correct the indentation.  You can never print "beepboop" (which you probably want to print for 15 and 30) because in both cases `num%3` will be zero, so you will have already printed "beep".  Once you know at least one of the two is zero, try checking if the other is *non*-zero,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong indent

```
for num in range(1, 31):
    if (num % 5 == 0) or (num % 3 == 0):
        if num % 3 == 0:
            print("beep")
        elif num % 5 == 0:
            print("boop")
        else:
            print("beepboop")
    else:
        print(num)
```